# How to use Visual Studio 2008 to attach to a DLL running in Windows Mobile 6.53?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

How to use Visual Studio 2008 to attach to a DLL running in Windows Mobile 6.53?
OR How to debug a Local Authentication Plugin DLL running in Windows Mobile 6.53 using VS 2008?
I am trying to debug the sample LAP (Local Authentication Plugin), provided in C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CPP\win32\LAP
Signed and copied the lap dll to \windows on the device.
Connected to Windows Mobile 6.53 device via usb cable and Active Sync.
How do I run it in the debugger? I try 'Attach To Process' from the VS debugger but am unsure which process contains the LAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Attach To Process' is the right thing to do, but you do need to know which process is loading your dll. If your dll is a Windows CE Service, then you could try attaching to the process [Services.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446909.aspx#implement_network_service_topic2)

Comment: It is the screen locking stuff for authentication see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms926467.aspx. I shall try connecting to services.exe and report the results here

Comment: Thanks! Here is what I did. Signed and copied over my DLL as usual, to /windows on the device, using ActiveSync.
In VS 2008, choose Debug and then Attach to Process.  In the popup dialog, under Transport, choose ‘Smart Device’, ‘Windows 6.53 Professional’ and then connect.
Click the checkbox ‘Show processes from all users’. Choose the process your DLL runs in. In my case it was ‘services.exe’. Click Connect and your debugger will stop at breakpoints.